# Split values returned

Tags: powershell

I have a script which returns few names as below. The value "mark" "ted" are combined since the function within the script is returning this together but in two different lines.. Hence $name always get these two names together (which runs in a loop) and I wanted to split them and call these two values separate within the script. Is this possible? Could you please help?

```
$list | % {
    $name = student.identifier
    Write-Output $name
    Write-Output Hello
```

Current Output:

```
jake
Hello
mark
ted
Hello
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant code? What is `student` and should it be prefixed with `$`? You don't seem to be accessing anything from `$list` in the example

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to split on each line break, am I right?

For Example:

```
$list = "jake
mark
ted"

$list.Count
>1
```

That means there's only one element in our list, which happens to be three lines long.  Let's split it.

```
$list.Split("`n")
```

We're calling the Split method on our variable, and telling it to split on the special ``n` character, which is a PowerShell line-break.

If I were to take the count now, check it out.

```
$list = $list.Split("`n")
$list.Count
>3
```

And now to run your code (modified a bit)

```
 $list | % {
    $name = $_
    Write-output $name
    Write-Output "Hello"
    }
jake
Hello
mark
Hello
ted
Hello
```

Sounds like what you're asking for.  If I misunderstood, please let me know.